# Generating a Mandarin numbering system

Tags: prolog

**I'm constructing a Prolog program that counts from 0 to 10,000. I have it working for 0 to 99. I need help with 100 to 1,000.** The numbering system can be found at http://mandarin.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/numbers.htm

```
/* líng */
mandarin(A, 0,[number,zero,nonfirst]):- name(A,[108,236,110,103]).

/* yī */
mandarin(A, 1, [number,unit,first]):- name(A,[121,299]).

/* èr */
mandarin(A, 2, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[232,114]).

/* sān */
mandarin(A, 3, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[115,257,110]).

/* sì */
mandarin(A, 4, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[115,236]).

/* wǔ */
mandarin(A, 5, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[119,468]).

/* liù */
mandarin(A, 6, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[108,105,249]).

/* qī */
mandarin(A, 7, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[113,299]).

/* bā */
mandarin(A, 8, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[98,257]).

/* jiǔ */
mandarin(A, 9, [number,unit,nonfirst]):- name(A,[106,105,468]).

/* shí */
mandarin(A, 10, [number,ten,first]):- name(A,[115,104,237]).

/* bǎi */
mandarin(A, 100, [number,hundred,first]):- name(A,[121,236,32,98,462,237]).

/* yì qiān */

mandarin(A, 1000, [number,thousand,first]):- name(A,[121,236,32,113,105,257,110]).

/* yì wàn */

mandarin(A, 10000, [number,thousand,first]):- name(A,[121,236,32,119,224,110]).
```

The function below successfully outputs the mandarin numbers from 0 - 9 in the form of `A = lìng, B = 0 A = yī, B = 1`:

```
mandarin(A, B, []):- mandarin(A,B,[number, zero, _]); mandarin(A, B, [number,unit,_]).
```

The function below successfully outputs the mandarin numbers from 10 - 99 in the form of `A = [shí] B = 10 A = [shí, yī], B = 11`:

```
mandarin(A, B, [number]):-
    mandarin(C, D, [_,ten,_]),
    write('A = ['), write(C), write(']'), nl, 
    write('B = '), write(D),
    mandarin(E, F, [_,unit,_]),
    append([C], [E], J),
    B is D + F,
    B < 100,
    flatten(J,A).
```

**I need help defining a function that counts from 100 - 1,000.**

So far, I have:

```
mandarin(A, B, [number]):-
    mandarin(X, Y, [_,hundred,_]),
    write('A = ['), write(X), write(']'),
    nl, write('B = '), write(Y),
    mandarin(C, D, [_,zero,_]),
    mandarin(E, F, [_,unit,_]),
    append([X], [C], U), append([U], [E], J),
    B is Y + D + F,
    B >= 100,
    flatten(J,A).
```

Which **incorrectly** outputs:

```
A = [yì bǎí]
B = 100
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, yī],
B = 101 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, èr],
B = 102 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, sān],
B = 103 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, sì],
B = 104 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, wǔ],
B = 105 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, liù],
B = 106 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, qī],
B = 107 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, bā],
B = 108 
A = ['yì bǎí', lìng, jiǔ],
B = 109 
A = [[èr,yì bǎí]]
B = 200
A = [èr, 'yì bǎí', lìng, yī],
B = 201 
...
```

**Incorrectly**, because it skips the numbers 110 - 199, 210 - 299, etc.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you use such a complicated schema, so I've modified the 'facts'

```
mandarin(líng,  0, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(yī,    1, [number,unit,first]).
mandarin(èr,    2, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(sān,   3, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(sì,    4, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(wǔ,    5, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(liù,   6, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(qī,    7, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(bā ,   8, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(jiǔ,   9, [number,unit,nonfirst]).
mandarin(shí,   10, [number,ten,first]).
mandarin('yì bǎí',  100, [number,hundred,first]).

mandarin(B, [number]):-
    mandarin(_, H, [_,hundred,_]),
    mandarin(_, D, [_,ten,_]),
    mandarin(_, H1, [_,unit,_]),
    mandarin(_, D1, [_,unit,_]),
    mandarin(_, F1, [_,unit,_]),
    B is H*H1 + D*D1 + F1, B>100.
```

The relevant change is on 0, I've tagged it as unit. Now, the B is computed as usual in decimal system.

Comment: I am trying to implement your strategy, but I am having a lot of trouble. The code I had previously was oversimplified. I have updated my original post, I would really appreciate it if you could take a look. Additionally, your approach does successfully follow the decimal system now, and I just need help integrating that with my current program. Additionally, changing 0's tag to `unit` throws off the other functions. I look forward to your response.

Comment: In addition, I cannot simply include the special characters such as the 'í' in `líng` in my code. I'm using SWI-Prolog, and I get a `Syntax error` when compiling. Also, I see that you put some effort in your answer, and I know it's partially correct in terms of what I would like it to do. I would just like to integrate the mandarin numbers that are associated with the numbers with your code like I have in the new updated original post. Can you please help me with that?